# How to connect to a web service in the same solution from javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, web-services

I have a solution with several projects, one a web site the other a separate web server. (They will reside on different hosts.) I need to connect to the web service from some javascript in the web site. However, although this seems like an obvious, easy thing, I can't seem to get it right.
My web service works fine, I can connect to it from a Windows forms app in a separate project in the same solution.
What I have in my aspx file is this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/../WebService/WebService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calback(result)
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
    WebService.FunctionToCall("hello", callback);
</script>
```

However, the service reference says it can't access .. from ~

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path instead of ~/../

Comment: If I do that it is tied to the specific path on my computer, and so other people can't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that these two projects are in the same solution is irrelevant. You're hosting them on two different servers. Only the URL will matter.

Since the URL will differ between your development machine and the production (and no doubt, the test) machines, you'll have to handle that like any other URL that changes based on the environment - you'll need to use the config file.

---

I haven't completely tested this, but it looks like it's working:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Debug" >
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="<%$ AppSettings:webServiceUrl %>"  />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webServiceUrl" value="http://localhost:38759/Enumerations.asmx"/>
  </appSettings>
```

This actually did generate a script reference to the above web service.